# Regex to replace tabs with spaces after first word

Tags: regex

I managed to replace all tabs with spaces.
Find: \t
Replace: space

I'm not able to make this work when starting from the first word and ignore any tabs/spaces at the beginning of the line.

In this [example](https://regex101.com/r/9uxgFE/2) I managed to isolate the line from the first word onwards, but how can I now replace all individual tabs with individual spaces (flavor is Python)?

Best regards,

Comment: what is your regex

Comment: ^\s*([\w]+.*$), see also "example" link mentioned in question.

Comment: So, does my answer solve your issue?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you may capture different parts of a string and manipulate the capture group contents inside a `re.sub` using a lambda expression:

```
import re
s = """         s_Tmp   = 'ERROR: month "' | s_Month                 |       '" not valid - ABORT' | CHAR(13) | CHAR(10) ;"""
res = re.sub(r"^(\s*)(.*)", lambda x: "{}{}".format(x.group(1), x.group(2).replace("\t", " ")), s, flag=re.S)
print(res)
# =>        s_Tmp  = 'ERROR: month "' | s_Month       |   '" not valid - ABORT' | CHAR(13) | CHAR(10) ;
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/indiYl)

Note I pass `re.S` flag to the regex compiler so that `(.*)` (the second capturing group could match the whole rest of the string after the initial 0+ whitespaces (matched and captured into Group 1 with `(\s*)`).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(\s*)` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ whitespace
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars up to the string end.

The processing is done inside `lambda x: "{}{}".format(x.group(1), x.group(2).replace("\t", " "))`: tabs are replaced with spaces inside Group 2 value only.